# RuntimeError when importing keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to do some newb-level tutorial stuff with Keras and Python but I can't get past the keras module import. I'm working in Python 3.7.3 (on a Mac/no GPU) using a fresh virtualenv. Here's my `pip list`:

```
Package              Version
-------------------- -------
absl-py              0.8.1  
astor                0.8.0  
gast                 0.2.2  
google-pasta         0.1.7  
grpcio               1.24.3 
h5py                 2.10.0 
Keras                2.3.1  
Keras-Applications   1.0.8  
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0  
Markdown             3.1.1  
numpy                1.17.3 
opt-einsum           3.1.0  
pip                  19.3.1 
protobuf             3.10.0 
PyYAML               5.1.2  
scipy                1.3.1  
setuptools           41.4.0 
six                  1.12.0 
tensorboard          2.0.0  
tensorflow           2.0.0  
tensorflow-estimator 2.0.1  
termcolor            1.1.0  
Werkzeug             0.16.0 
wheel                0.33.6 
wrapt                1.11.2
```

And here's the error:

```
(venv) $ python -c "import keras"
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/KerasTutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "Users/me/KerasTutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils

...


  File "Users/me/KerasTutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 48, in getlines
    for mod in sys.modules.values():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Apparently tensorflow doesn't yet support Python 3.7. I tried with Python 3.6.4 and everything works fine.